# String outputs only one element in a for loop

Tags: apex

In my method I am passing 2 string elements in my for loop "advSearchResults", but for some reason, my  designated String variable is returning only one. My expected result should be a String showing both outputs separated by a new line.
Could you help me with what I am missing?

```
String dupRecString= '';

for(MergedSearchResult result: advSearchResults){
            if(result.isSelected == true){

                dupRecString ='Name: '+ result.companyName +', Master Id: '+ result.Masterid +', Salesforce Id: '+ acctMap.get(result.MasterId) +', Street Address: '+ result.addressline +', City: '+ result.city+', State: '+ result.state+', Zip: '+ result.zip+', Phone: '+ result.phone+', Email: '+ result.email +'\n';
}
```

Comment: I guess  you are overwriting the dupRecString  variable in each round. Maybe you should write 'dupRecString  = dupRecString  + 'Name: '+ result.companyName + ....'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting the values in each for loop, hence it will show only the values of the last iteration.

You will have to append the values in each loop, so replace your below code

```
dupRecString ='Name: '+ result.companyName +', Master Id: '+ result.Masterid +', Salesforce Id: '+ acctMap.get(result.MasterId) +', Street Address: '+ result.addressline +', City: '+ result.city+', State: '+ result.state+', Zip: '+ result.zip+', Phone: '+ result.phone+', Email: '+ result.email +'\n';
```

with

```
dupRecString +='Name: '+ result.companyName +', Master Id: '+ result.Masterid +', Salesforce Id: '+ acctMap.get(result.MasterId) +', Street Address: '+ result.addressline +', City: '+ result.city+', State: '+ result.state+', Zip: '+ result.zip+', Phone: '+ result.phone+', Email: '+ result.email +'\n';
```

or

```
dupRecString = dupRecString + 'Name: '+ result.companyName +', Master Id: '+ result.Masterid +', Salesforce Id: '+ acctMap.get(result.MasterId) +', Street Address: '+ result.addressline +', City: '+ result.city+', State: '+ result.state+', Zip: '+ result.zip+', Phone: '+ result.phone+', Email: '+ result.email +'\n';
```

Comment: That solved my issue. This completely escaped me. Thank you good Sir !!!